# When Im Trying to Sort the DataGrid ..Data Was Disappearing ..But Data Was Coming As Json Response and it was not Showing on UI with Sortable()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]      *Data Was Binding When Sortable() was clicked data was Disappearing on UI*

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Keys>(Model.baseKeysLocations).Name("SearchResultsGridLocation")
                                                //.Sortable()
                                                .Sortable(Sortable => Sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
                                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 450px" })
                                                .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
                                                .Reorderable(r => r.Columns(true))
                                                .Scrollable(s => s.Virtual(true))
                                                .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                                                .Pageable(p => p.Numeric(false).PreviousNext(false).Messages(m => m.Display("Total: {2}")))
                                                 .DataSource(ds => ds
                                                                .Ajax()
                                                                .AutoSync(true)
                                                                .Read(read => read.Action("Grid_KeyLocationRead", "Keys", new { @schdate = "", @drv = "" }))
                                                                .Model(m =>
                                                                {
                                                                    m.Id(f => f.UniqueId);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.Schedule);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.TableId).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.FobId).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.RoomKey).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.Community).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.Lease).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.RoomKey).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.Driver).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.Status).Editable(false);
                                                                    m.Field(f => f.FobId);
                                                                }
                                                                )
                                                            )

                                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                                    {
                                                        columns.Bound(f => f.UniqueId).Width("8rem").Hidden();
                                                        columns.Bound(f => f.TableId).Title("Id").Width("5rem").Hidden();
                                                        columns.Bound(f => f.RoomKey).Title("Key Location").Width("6rem");
                                                        columns.Bound(f => f.Community).Title("Community").Width("6rem");
                                                        columns.Bound(f => f.Lease).Title("Master").Width("6rem");
                                                        columns.Bound(f => f.Driver).Title("Driver").Width("6rem");
                                                        columns.Bound(client => client.Status).ClientTemplate("# if (Status == true) { #" + "IN" + "# } else  {#" + "OUT" + "# }  #").Title("Status").Width("8rem");
                                                    })
                                                    .Sortable()
    )
</div>
```

```
*Data Was Binding When Sortable() was clicked data was Disappearing on UI*
```

*Data Was Binding *[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfA4t.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRAmu.png
  *When Pressing Sort Function Data Is Disappearing*[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVSld.png

- Trying to Sort the DataGrid ..Data Was Disappearing ..But Data Was Coming As Json Response and it was not Showing on UI with Sortable() *

Answer (score 0):

```
 function SearchLocationResults(search) {
    $filter = new Array();
    var leaseuid = null, complexuid = null;
    if (search == true) {
        if ($("#baseLocationViewModel_ComplexUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() != '' && $("#baseLocationViewModel_ComplexUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() != null && $("#baseLocationViewModel_ComplexUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() != undefined) {
            $filter.push({ field: "Driver", operator: "isequalto", value: $("#baseLocationViewModel_DriverUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() });
            complexuid = $("#baseLocationViewModel_ComplexUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
        }
        if ($("#baseLocationViewModel_MasterUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() != '' && $("#baseLocationViewModel_MasterUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() != null && $("#baseLocationViewModel_MasterUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() != undefined) {
            $filter.push({ field: "LeaseUId", operator: "isequalto", value: $("#baseLocationViewModel_MasterUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value() });
            leaseuid = $("#baseLocationViewModel_MasterUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
        }
    }
    $(".loadermodel").removeClass('d-none');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Keys/Keys/Grid_KeyLocationRead',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,                    
        data: JSON.stringify({
            request: $filter, schedule: $("#baseLocationViewModel_Schedule").val(), driver: $("#baseLocationViewModel_DriverUId").data("kendoDropDownList").value(), _complexUId: complexuid, _leaseUId: leaseuid
        }),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#SearchResultsGridLocation").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data([]);
            $("#SearchResultsGridLocation").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(result);
            $(".loadermodel").addClass('d-none');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            $(".loadermodel").addClass('d-none');
        }
    });
}
```